# Cannot call method 'render' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have create "employees" array and want to generate mail using that array data. I create functionality for that in Node.js which is following.

I have also created one cron job which is called following functionality. When this function is called, the following error is raised:
`Cannot call method 'render' of undefined`

```
exports.missedWorksheets = function(req, res){

  var user = new User();

  var dailyCurrentDate = [];
  var dailyCurrentDate1 = [];
  var missedWorkByUser = [];
  var employees = [];
  var currentDate = moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  console.log(currentDate);
  var lastDate = moment(Date.now()).subtract(7,'days');
  var addedDate = moment(lastDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  console.log(addedDate);
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    dailyCurrentDate[i] = moment(addedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    dailyCurrentDate[i] = moment(dailyCurrentDate[i]).add(1,'days');
    dailyCurrentDate1[i] = moment(dailyCurrentDate[i]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    addedDate = moment(dailyCurrentDate1[i]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(dailyCurrentDate1[i]);
  }

  User.find().exec(function(err, missedUsers) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      Worksheet.find().populate('employee','._id').exec(function(err, missedWorksheets){
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
          });
        }else{
          for(var i=0; i<missedUsers.length; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<missedWorksheets.length; j++){
              if(String(missedUsers[i]._id) != String(missedWorksheets[j].employee._id))
              {
                employees[i] = missedUsers[i];
              }
            }
          }
          async.waterfall([
                          function(done)
                          {
                            console.log("Async called.");
                            done(err,employees);
                          },
                          function(employees,done) {
                            console.log("Template fetch called.");
                            app.render('templates/weekly-worksheet-checking', {
                  //user: user,
                  employee: employees,
                }, function(err,emailHTML) {
                  done(err,emailHTML,employees);
                });
                          },
              // If valid email, send reset email using service
              function(emailHTML,employees, done) {
                console.log("1-mail called.");
                var mailToEmployee = config.mailer.from;
                var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailer.options);
                //users.getActiveAdminUsers(function(activeAdminUsers){
                  var receivers=mailToEmployee+',';
                // for (var i in activeAdminUsers){
                //  var activeAdminUser =   activeAdminUsers[i];
                //  receivers = receivers + activeAdminUser.email+',';
                // }
                var mailOptions = {
                  to: 'hareshr@systemintegration.in',
                  from: config.mailer.from,
                  subject: 'Unfill WorksheetList of Previous year',
                  html: emailHTML
                };
                smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                  if (!err) {
                    //  Notification.email = leaveResponse.employee.email;
                    //  Notification.summary = leaveResponse.leaveScheduleType;
                    //  notifications.approveLeaveNotification(req,res,Notification.email,Notification.summary);
                    res.jsonp(employees);
                  }

                  done(err);
                });
                //});
}
],function(err) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
    return res.send({
     message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
   });
  }
});
}
});

}
});
};
```

Comment: `.render` appears to be a function call on `app`.  Your code as posted does not define `app`.

Comment: Sorry i have submit code with "app.render" by mistake.but i have used "res.render" at that place and same error was occurre.please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, your `app` object is not defined.
Since you seem to call that method in a callback function, maybe the `app` object is defined in another scope of your JS code.

Have a look at the `bind` method.

**Documentation:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

**More details on how to use it:**
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/#JavaScript8217s_Bind_Method

> In other words, bind () allows us to easily set which specific object
>   will be bound to this when a function or method is invoked.

Comment: Sorry i have submit code with "app.render" by mistake.but i have used "res.render" at that place and same error was occurred.please give me solution